# Unable to load DLL 'tensorflow' on Windows 2012 R2 Server

Tags: c#, tensorflow, machine-learning, ml.net

I have created an image classifier using ML.Net Model Builer in Visual Studio on Windows 10.  It has been compiled in to a Console application.  This runs fine on the development machine and other Windows 10 machines.
I need to deploy it to a Windows 2012 R2 server but when I start the application I get this error message:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Excepti
on has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.Target
InvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. -
--> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by th
e target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
'tensorflow': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Excep
tion from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)
   at Tensorflow.c_api.TF_NewGraph()
   at Tensorflow.Graph..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow.TensorFlowUtils.LoadTFSession(IExceptionContext ec
tx, Byte[] modelBytes, String modelFile)
   at Microsoft.ML.Vision.ImageClassificationModelParameters..ctor(IHostEnvironm
ent env, ModelLoadContext ctx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
 Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, B
inder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstanceCore
(Object[] ctorArgs)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes](IHostEnviron
ment env, Type signatureType, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[
] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes,TSig](IHostEn
vironment env, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
 env, TRes& result, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env
, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
env, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, String name, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.MulticlassPredictionTransformer.Create(IHostEnvironment
env, ModelLoadContext ctx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
 Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Objec
t[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invoke
Attr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstanceCore
(Object[] ctorArgs)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes](IHostEnviron
ment env, Type signatureType, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[
] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes,TSig](IHostEn
vironment env, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
 env, TRes& result, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env
, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
env, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, String name, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1..ctor(IHostEnvironment env, ModelLoad
Context ctx)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain.Create(IHostEnvironment env, ModelLoadC
ontext ctx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
 Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Objec
t[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invoke
Attr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstanceCore
(Object[] ctorArgs)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes](IHostEnviron
ment env, Type signatureType, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[
] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes,TSig](IHostEn
vironment env, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
 env, TRes& result, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env
, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
env, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, String name, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1..ctor(IHostEnvironment env, ModelLoad
Context ctx)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain.Create(IHostEnvironment env, ModelLoadC
ontext ctx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
 Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Objec
t[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invoke
Attr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstanceCore
(Object[] ctorArgs)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes](IHostEnviron
ment env, Type signatureType, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[
] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes,TSig](IHostEn
vironment env, TRes& result, String name, String options, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
 env, TRes& result, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env
, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, RepositoryReader rep, Entry ent, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment
env, TRes& result, RepositoryReader rep, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig](IHostEnvironment env, T
Res& result, RepositoryReader rep, String dir, Object[] extra)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load(Stream stream, DataViewSchema& in
putSchema)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load(String filePath, DataViewSchema&
inputSchema)
   at Gatehouse.AI.KeyClassification.KeyClassifierModel..ctor()
   at delmedelme.Proxy.IsKey() in C:\xxxxxxxx.cs:line 18
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same issue.

The solution was to Add Feature "Desktop Experience", which is not by default included in W2012 installation.

I hope that helps in your case!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: We still have not definitively identified the issue.  However, after testing on numerous machines - it appears that it was nothing to do with the OS but more whether the processor supported AVX.  The original issue was identified when running on a e6540 Xeon which predated AVX.  The code works fine on Windows 2012 R2 with a later processor that supports AVX.